# Certificate exception when building iOS native extension

Tags: ios, air, certificate

I have certificates for developer and distribution . I signed AIR apps using those certificates, and all work (I publiched 5 games to AppStore, all OK).

But when I try to compile an iOS native extension, I get:

> **Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer extension.**